# Atomicity and CAS operations in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Currently I am trying to understand how to implement a CAS operation in mongodb properly to support optimistic locking. I've found out that updates in `mongodb` are atomic but I am not sure what this means (only the document rewrite is atomic or all cycle of update, including search for corresponding document and its rewriting, is atomic?). Lets consider following example.

1. Some document exists in some collection with `_id` value set to 123 and has attribute `cas_val` set to 10.
2. The first client wants to update `cas_val` of the document with `_id` equal to 123 to 11.
3. The second client wants to update `cas_val` of the document with `_id` equal to 123 to 11.
4. Both clients operate at the same time and operations can interleave.

So, is it possible that **both** operation succeed in case when no other updates to the document with `_id` 123 were performed?

P.S. Is there some build in technique in `mongodb` for the optimistic locking scenario?

Comment: using $inc alone will not allow you to implement optimistic locking since you presumably will be changing other fields.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct technique for optimistic locking is to use the "update if current" which is described in detail [in MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/#update-if-current).

The key to this technique is that the update condition cannot simply be `{_id:123}` but rather it has to be `{_id:123, cas_val: 10}` and the update clause would $set appropriate fields including incrementing the cas_val to 11.

Now the thread that "loses" the race and arrives second will NOT find a matching document to update and will need to "retry" by refetching the document (now with cas_val 11) and trying again.  The way you find out if the update succeeded or not is by checking the writeConcern structure (it will indicate how many records were affected in "n" and whether existing record was updated in "updatedExisting" field).

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. That is exactly what I was intended to do.

Comment: @gkuzmin although the other answer is definitely also relevant, I think you should mark this one as 'accepted as the best answer'?

Comment: Yes, this answer makes more sense these days.

Answer (score 1):

If you use atomic updates with the correct operators, you don't need to fetch the document then update it, so the updates won't interleave (at least the data set will still be consistent). It seems you want an [`$inc` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/inc/#op._S_inc) here BTW.

Comment: I definitely want to fetch documents and then update them in the optimistic locking way. And it seems that it is impossible to build optimistic locking using the `$inc` operator. At least I can not understand how to do it using `$inc`. What can you say about the example BTW?

Comment: In this case you might consider adding a `version` field, which is an increment. Your `update` operation will match both `_id: 123` and `version: x`, so if the version has been incremented meanwhile, this document won't be updated. To check if the document has been update you can check the `n` number of the `getlasterror` message (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596846/how-to-return-number-of-updated-objects-in-mongodb)

Comment: That is exactly what I was wondering about! Thank you!
P.S. In my example `cas_value` plays `version` field role.

Comment: then this is not the correct sequence - one thread will update it to 11 and the other thread to 12 but the second thread will overwrite the other updates that the first thread made.